# Eclipselink JPA NoSQL No Persistence Provider

Tags: java, mongodb, jpa, eclipselink

I'm trying to connect my mongoDb with JPA using Eclipselink, but got an error. I have tried a few things. But I got the same error every time. All imports are with Maven. 
This is my Persistence.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="mongodb" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>eclipselink.Order</class>
    <class>eclipselink.Item</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="org.eclipse.persistence.nosql.adapters.mongo.MongoPlatform"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.nosql.connection-spec" value="org.eclipse.persistence.nosql.adapters.mongo.MongoConnectionSpec"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.nosql.property.mongo.port" value="27017"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.nosql.property.mongo.host" value="127.0.0.1"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.nosql.property.mongo.db" value="odm_eclipselink"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

En this is how I create my EntityManager

```
EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("mongodb").createEntityManager();
```

My error :

No Persistence provider for EntityManager named mongodb

It's weird because JPA create the database in mongodb. I check that in my commandprompt.

```
> show dbs
admin            0.000GB
local            0.000GB
odm_eclipselink  0.000GB
```